# Scipy.misc.imread flatten argument -- converting to grey scale

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to understand how this method transform an image in grey scale (if it uses a simple mean or a weighted mean) -- I have to reference this method.

From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) I know that this method calls the `convert(‘F’)` method.

From Pillow/PIL [source code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/Image.py), I can find this method, however, I couldn't find what it does when the `mode` parameter is set to 'F'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the docstring of the `convert` method of the `Image` object (seen in the code that you linked to), there is this:

> When translating a color image to black and white (mode "L"),
>   the library uses the ITU-R 601-2 luma transform::
>
> L = R * 299/1000 + G * 587/1000 + B * 114/1000

Apparently this is also how `mode='F'` is handled.

Here's an example:

```
In [2]: from PIL import Image
```

Create an array for the demonstration:

```
In [3]: x = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(4, 4, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
```

Send the array through the conversion to an Image and back to an array, using `mode='F'` in the `convert` method:

```
In [4]: np.array(Image.fromarray(x).convert('F'))
Out[4]: 
array([[ 3.24499989,  6.30499983,  1.86899996,  4.54400015],
       [ 3.54399991,  5.04300022,  4.63000011,  0.29899999],
       [ 2.0539999 ,  3.29900002,  1.85800004,  1.76100004],
       [ 3.9289999 ,  4.76100016,  5.76100016,  2.47799993]], dtype=float32)
```

Multiply `x` by the factors shown in the docstring of `convert`:

```
In [5]: f = np.array([0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

In [6]: x.dot(f)
Out[6]: 
array([[ 3.245,  6.305,  1.869,  4.544],
       [ 3.544,  5.043,  4.63 ,  0.299],
       [ 2.054,  3.299,  1.858,  1.761],
       [ 3.929,  4.761,  5.761,  2.478]])
```

If we convert to `np.float32`, we see exactly the same values as created by the `convert` method:

```
In [7]: x.dot(f).astype(np.float32)
Out[7]: 
array([[ 3.24499989,  6.30499983,  1.86899996,  4.54400015],
       [ 3.54399991,  5.04300022,  4.63000011,  0.29899999],
       [ 2.0539999 ,  3.29900002,  1.85800004,  1.76100004],
       [ 3.9289999 ,  4.76100016,  5.76100016,  2.47799993]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: _You are a scientific godsend._ Thanks for teasing this undocumented conversion out of the underlying data. Nowhere is it stated that the conversion to mode `F` (floating point) generalizes the conversion to mode `L` (grayscale luma). Whereas converting to mode `L` *coerces* the results to 8-bit unsigned integers, converting to mode `F` *preserves* the fractional portion of this grayscale reduction. This, in turn, now explains why the deprecated `scipy.misc.imread()` function implements the `flatten` parameter by converting to mode `F` rather than `L`. `</phew>`

Answer (score 0):

The mode parameter 'F' stands for 'floating point'.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.new("F", (2,2))
pixels = im.load()
pixels[0,0] = 255.0
pixels[1,0] = 200.0
pixels[0,1] = 100.0
pixels[1,1] = 20.0
im.show()
```